# Access violation reading from memory using clGetDeviceInfo

Tags: c++, opencl

I am getting a "sometimes" access violation error; the program works sometimes and spits out device name and type, and other times it just throws an access violation exception.

The output (from printf) from my program is as follows:

> *unnecessary stuff*
>
> Number of detected OpenCL devices: 2

So obviously i am detecting two devices per that platform (see the for loop in the code).

The number is given by the **getDeviceInfo** function and stored in a dummy variable, so maybe there is a problem in that function.

I noticed during debugging that
**getDeviceInfo** returned

> 0x0000000d49eff270 {0x000001f1ff027af0}   _cl_device_id**

I am guessing that the first bit (0x0000000d49eff270), is the memory location for the beginning of the array of devices.
However when I access my devices array in this line

```
cl_device_id device = devices[i]; //see me in the main inside the second for loop
```

I get this value (for devices[i] and device) instead:

> 0xcccccccccccccccc {...}  _cl_device_id*

Anyways, the program continues to try and fetch device info using the function **displayDeviceDetails** and it fails with an access violation on **clGetDeviceInfo** like mentioned previously.

What happened? Why does it sometimes work as well, cause if there is something wrong. It shouldn't work at all right?

I attach relevant source code:

**getDeviceInfo**:

```
cl_device_id* getDeviceInfo(cl_platform_id platform_id, cl_device_type device_type, cl_uint &numOfDev)
 {
    cl_int error = 0;
    cl_uint numberOfDevices = 0;

    /* Determine how many devices are in the platform */
    error = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, device_type, 0, NULL, &numberOfDevices);
    if (checkCLError(error, "Unable to obtain any OpenCL device info")) 
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    numOfDev = numberOfDevices;

    /* allocate memory for the devices array (pointer) */
    cl_device_id* devices = (cl_device_id*)alloca(sizeof(cl_device_id) * numberOfDevices);

    /* Load device information into array devices */
    error = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, device_type, numberOfDevices, devices, NULL);

    if (checkCLError(error, "Unable to obtain device info")) 
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Number of detected OpenCL devices: %d\n", numberOfDevices);
    return devices;
}
```

**displayDeviceDetails:**

```
void displayDeviceDetails(cl_device_id dev_id, cl_device_info param_name, const     char* paramNameAsStr)
{
    cl_int error = 0;
    size_t paramSize = 0;

    /* Get Device Info size */
    error = clGetDeviceInfo(dev_id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize);
    if (checkCLError(error, "Unable to obtain device info")) 
    {
        return;
    }

    switch (param_name)
    {
    case CL_DEVICE_TYPE:
        {
        cl_device_type* devType = (cl_device_type*)alloca(sizeof(cl_device_type)* paramSize);
        error = clGetDeviceInfo(dev_id, param_name, paramSize, devType, NULL);
        if (checkCLError(error, "Unable to obtain a specific device info"))
        {
            return;
        }
        switch (*devType)
        {
        case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU:
            printf("\tCPU Detected\n");
            break;
        case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU:
            printf("\tGPU Detected\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\tOther stuff Detected\n");
        }
        break;
        }

    case CL_DEVICE_NAME:
        {
        char* devName = (char*)alloca(sizeof(CL_DEVICE_NAME)*paramSize);
        error = clGetDeviceInfo(dev_id, param_name, paramSize, devName, NULL);
        printf("\tName: %s\n", devName);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
int main() {

    cl_platform_id* platforms;
    cl_uint numOfPlatforms;
    cl_int error;

    error = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numOfPlatforms);
    if (checkCLError(error, "Unable to find OpenCL Plaftorms"))
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Number of OpenCL platform found: %d\n", numOfPlatforms);

    platforms = (cl_platform_id*)alloca(sizeof(cl_platform_id)*        numOfPlatforms);
    
    error = clGetPlatformIDs(numOfPlatforms, platforms, NULL);  // This line   initializes ""something"". Delete and u will get access violation

    for (cl_uint i = 0; i < numOfPlatforms; ++i) {
        printf("\n--------------------\nThe %d th platform\n-----------------    ---\n",i+1);

        displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE,     "CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE");
        displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, "CL_PLATFORM_VERSION");
        displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, "CL_PLATFORM_NAME");
        displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, "CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR");
        displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS, "CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS");
    
        cl_uint numOfDevices = 0;
        cl_device_id* devices = getDeviceInfo(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, numOfDevices);

        for (cl_uint i = 0; i < numOfDevices; ++i) 
        {
            printf("\tDevice (%d) Information\n\t----------------------\n",i);

            cl_device_id device = devices[i];
            displayDeviceDetails(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME, "CL_DEVICE_NAME");
            displayDeviceDetails(device, CL_DEVICE_TYPE, "CL_DEVICE_TYPE");
        }
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code is C while the tag says it's C++.

Comment: @TheTechel It is some weird Frankensteins monster both C and C++, look at the function signature for `getDeviceInfo`.

Comment: I tend to confuse the two. What do I do with the tag? or the code? @George

Comment: @zellwwf Just leave it :-) The code is not compilable C, I guess the other guy was just confused because it's C-style code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `alloca()`. Stop that! The `alloca()` function allocates size bytes of space in the stack frame of the caller, which you then return (which destroys the stack frame).

Comment: Haha that worked like a charm! Thanks I didn't know that before

Comment: Also, when you switch to malloc, you also then need a free. Or switch to modern C++ and use a unique_ptr which deletes when it goes out of scope.

Comment: I remember that from school, deallocate when using malloc and I will look into the unique_ptr seems like it saves some headaches. Thanks a lots